# I want to use SESSION in Node.js like PHP

Tags: javascript, php, node.js

* Hello, I don't know English Well. So understand me please.

### English

I want to use Session Data that PHP set like login info.

### Korean

로그인 정보 같이, PHP에서 설정한 세션 정보를 쓰고 싶은데 어떻게 해야 할지 잘 모르겠어요.

### Code

session data was set by PHP.

server.js:

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(3000);

var load_history_count = 10;
var load_history_data = new Array();
// These Data is to load chat data by chatted others before access chat room.

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket){
  for(var i=0;i<load_history_data.length;i++){
    socket.emit("getMsg", load_history_data[i]);
  }
  // These Code is to load chat data by chatted others before access chat room.

  socket.on("login", function(){
    socket.emit("getMsg", "This is your NickName:"+session.login_info['nickname']);
    // I want to use session data in here like session.login_info.nickname
    // or session.login_info['nickname'];
    // How can I use session data?
  });

  socket.on("sendMsg", function(data){
    load_history_data.push(data);
    if(load_history_data.length > load_history_count) load_history_data.shift();
    socket.broadcast.emit("getMsg", data);
    socket.emit("getMsg", data);
  });
});
```

client.js:

```
var url = "My Site Url";
var port = 3000;
var socket = io.connect(url+":"+port);

jQuery(function($){
    socket.emit("access");  
    socket.on("getMsg", function(data){
        $("<div>"+data+"</div>").appendTo($("#content"));
    });

    function sendMsg(){
        var a = $("#input");
        if(a.val() != ""){
            socket.emit("sendMsg", a.val());
            a.val("");
        }
    }

    $("#input").keydown(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) sendMsg();
    });

    $("#submit").click(function(){
        sendMsg();
    });
});
```

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/sessions

Comment: Hum... I'm not sure, but I guess You don't need session in Node.js

Comment: If the session data is set by PHP, there's no easy way to access that in Node. PHP stores the data internally, and uses a cookie as a key (somewhat simplified), and even if you got the key from the cookie, you can't access the data. There are modules available for session handling in Node as well, and they work the same way, setting a key, and storing the data locally, and no, you can't really access that data from PHP, unless you store it in a DB and have access to the DB from both languages.

Comment: @Quentin How can I use https://npmjs.org/package/sessions ?

Comment: @adeneo [Login=>PHP, Chat=>Node.js] This is impossible?

Comment: @adeneo i heard that PHP actually stores the session data in a file somewhere; assuming you know where those files are/where the PHP directory is, couldn't you conceivably access those files and somehow parse data? It'd be hard, but couldn't you do it?

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae The code I posted is just test code for use session.

Comment: @WebEngine it probably isn't impossible to do that, but you might need to implement your own sessions system where files are easily accessible by both languages. And remember, they aren't supposed to be used together

Comment: @Markasoftware - That's true, the data is stored in files, and even most databases uses files to store data, so no suprise there. Node supports the use of any database as a store for the session middleware, so that seems a lot easier, just connect to the DB from both node and PHP.

Comment: @adeneo that has potential

Comment: @adeneo If I don't use session. How can I know user info. I can't get user id and password.

Comment: @WebEngine it would act like session, just not technically session

Comment: Again, both PHP and Node can access just about any database, and if you're already using mysql in PHP, there's middleware for that in node as well, then you can use a key stored in a cookie to access the data in both languages.

Comment: @adeneo use cookie [PHPSESSID]? like column : phpsessid, name, data? It will make too many db data. How can I delete it?

Comment: It's basically how sessions work, it's just a key/value storage, but to have access from two servers you have to create your own sessions, or at least create some sort of system where you can access the data from both, and it shouldn't be to hard, but noone here can make it for you, all we can do is suggest how it could be done.

Comment: @adeneo I will make db session expire 1 days. What do you think?

Comment: BUT WAIT! There's still hope! https://npmjs.org/package/groan

Comment: @Markasoftware It is very interesting. but, I think that I can't know dir what session saved. and I upload this chatroom source on web development site maybe when I complete making chat room.

Comment: ...... Why everybody doesn't answer posting here? just comment only.

Comment: @WebEngine 2 reasons: we don't really have a solid solution, just some random ideas that we want to refine, and the question is on hold right now, preventing us from being able to answer.